# Vue.js: Blocking a following request till the previous one is done

Tags: javascript, vue.js, request, vuejs2, action

I have posts in my application which a user can either like or dislike: there are two different buttons and each of them shows how many likes/dislikes a post gets. Currently, I am struggling to resolve a bug of this feature. If I quickly click on these buttons, one after another, and then stop, these buttons continue to show this clicking behaviour and there are more requests appear for a short while in my console.

Here is what I have in my component:

```
<template>
...
<div>
      <a style="cursor: default"
         @click.pointer="dislikePost(getPost.id)">
        <i class="icon-minus"/>{{ getPost.dislikes }} Dislike
      </a>
      <a style="cursor: default"
         @click="likePost(getPost.id)">
        <i class="icon-plus" />{{ getPost.likes }} Like
      </a>
    </div>
...
</template>
```

And here is what I have in my store:

```
...
actions: {
likePost({ commit }, postId) {
  http
    .post(`${config.api}/posts/${postId}/like`)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      commit('load_post', data);
    });
},
dislikePost({ commit }, postId) {
  http
    .post(`${config.api}/posts/${postId}/dislike`)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      commit('load_post', data);
    });
},
},
mutations: {
load_posts(state, posts) {
  state.posts = posts;
},
},
...
```

Comment: Count the amount of clicks and compare it to the amount of requests (just log it inside `.then()`) Perhaps it's just takes some time for the action to finish

Comment: Yes, I believe that one action didn't finish before the next one started. But how can I check if it was finished then? I want to check it and only then allow another action to start.

Comment: Is `data` an object? Or what are you committing to `state.posts` there? Can't you just check if the value you are committing is already in `state.posts` before doing `commit('load_post', data)` ?

Comment: You need a custom tracking of what's going on, ie a variable that knows if request is waiting response or not. Then you can easily use `:disable="isLoading"` on a link to prevent multiple clicks while loading. Remember to clear the variable later on when request and refresh is done!